# how to continously move series of images from left to right on screen in Qt?

Tags: qt

I have a certain window width. I have series of images of constant width and height coming In. I want to scroll them from left to right in one window.I use QLabels to display images. I have shown below pictorially.

<--certain window width -->

---

| img1           |

then image 2 comes which should be displayed to the left of img1

---

| img2 img1     |

then image 3 comes and goes to left of img2

---

| img3 img2 img1  |

How do I achieve this is Qt?

Regards

Comment: I can help you in this. But want to understand little more about "scroll them from left to right in one window". it means, it is restricted to scroll from right to left?. Can you write more in detail.

Comment: @Jeet:Thanks Jeet.  "scroll them from left to right in one window" means img1 should keep on going towards the right side and by doing so will accomodate img2 on its left side and then img1 and img2 go together right side and accomodate for img3. Does this help jeet?

Comment: From my understanding i have given an answer. Hope that help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is  a code example to add the images left side to the previous one.
Code comment will explain in detail. The overall structure is ScrollArea->ScrollAreaWidget->HorizontalLayout->No.Of.QLable (Image Display)

```
//scroll area
QScrollArea *scrollArea;
    //widget inside scroll area
    QWidget *scrollAreaWidgetContents;
    //Horizontal Box Layout
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
    //Image loaded to find the width and height to resize the scroll area.   
    QImage img(QString::fromUtf8("../../../Downloads/red_star.png"));

    scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this->centralWidget());
    //Adding the size of the scrollbar with the image width
    int intWidth=img.width()*2.5+qApp->style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_ScrollBarExtent)*2;
    //Adding the size of the scrollbar with the image Height
    int intHeight=img.height()+qApp->style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_ScrollBarExtent)*2;

    scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    //Sizing the scroll area and the inside widget  
    scrollArea->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0,intWidth ,intHeight));
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
    scrollAreaWidgetContents = new QWidget();
    scrollAreaWidgetContents->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, intWidth, intHeight));
    Making the main window width to the scroll area width
    this->setFixedWidth(scrollArea->width());
    horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
    scrollArea->setWidget(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
    //Image static array
    QString strImages[]= {"../../../Downloads/red_star.png","../../../Downloads/green_star.png","../../../Downloads/yellow_star.png"};
    //Add the image in the left side of the previous one (Note the color)
    for(int iCount=0; iCount<3; iCount++)
    {
        QLabel *label = new QLabel(QStringLiteral("label"),scrollAreaWidgetContents);
        label->setPixmap(QPixmap(strImages[iCount]));
        //Adding the new image to the left of previous image
        horizontalLayout->insertWidget(0,label);
    }
```

[image]

> Check the Image color from the static array

Comment: :@Jeet. I am having fixed size window just like a acting stage. Your new(orange) img1 actor comes and should go to the end of the window and then disappear. I should not see it again.Like a ribbon going with images on it. Your code has given me new inputs towards features for my application dev. Thanks Jeet for taking time. Is it possible to change your code now so to make the imges go away without the need of scrollbar.

Comment: i shown the scroll bar for your understanding. If you don't want then add this line "scrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);". And once the image that disappear from the view then deallocate it from the QLabel. And also the QLable too. Try this. If you need let me know for the code change.

Comment: I have a QMainWindow.Inside it is QWidget .Inside it is  QGridLayout. In QGridLayout, I have all QLabels to display images. How do I implement your concept now? Thanks Jeet.

Comment: Yes correct. So now you can change the above given code, appropriate (answer) to your widgets and complete the logic.

Comment: This is the code I came up with. kindly make necessary assumptions. QScrollArea scroll = new QScrollArea(); scroll->setGeometry(...understood..); scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true); scrollAreaWidgetContents = new QWidget(); scrollArea->setWidget(scrollAreaWidgetContents); QLabel *label = new QLabel(scrollAreaWidgetContents); label->setPixmap(QPixmap(..some image....)); ui->gridlayout->addWidget(label,0,0,0); The gridlayout doesnot have the option of displaying to the left. How do I overcome this?

Comment: Finally made it work. The only problem I have is "flicker" between the images. Many thanks Jeet.